# Like box - opening in new window

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

Trying to implement a FB like box iframe in my website gulbrand.net.

Following code is used:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgulbrandnet&amp;width=500&amp;height=1000&amp;
colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;
header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
width:500px; height:1000px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It appears allright on my testsite.  A link to the gulbrand.net FB page with a like button.  And posts from the FB page.

But:  When pressing the like button a new browser window (IE) for login in to FB is opened.  I am already logged into FB and would expect that I liked the FB page automatically (and maybe that the count of likes would increase with 1).  When I put in my password in the login panel just a new blank page is opened.  And I have not "liked" the FB page.

Anything I do wrong?  Solutions?

Comment: The code seemed to get lost when I posted the question.  Here it is:  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgulbrandnet&amp;width=500&amp;height=1000&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:1000px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: can you post a code example of what you have so far.

Comment: click edit and hi-light your code and click the brackets button.

Comment: post the code in the question using the brackets button so its readable and doesn't get lost

Comment: What is the brackets button??

Comment: There is a button with brackets that you click on to auto format/hilight code depending on language. You need to select your code and click the button with an image of {} to give it that block. The preview should show the code in front of a gray box.

Comment: (The code seems to be on the top her now....  Have now understood how to use the brackets...).   Have tried the page with this code in a Chrome browser.  Same result - opens a new window for new login.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening because you are using IE is that it is creating a new process for every tab you are making. It also blocks cross domain cookies by default. Problems with losing session cookies in popups have also been noted. This is mostly specific to IE8 from what I have heard, but you haven't mentioned what version. You can read more about this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx It is an ongoing issue.

What I recommend is you use a chrome frame: http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?prefersystemlevel=true to redirect users to use a better browser like chrome. It is easy to integrate into any website. Learn more at the link above. Let us know if this is happening to you only on IE8 or chrome or other browsers too.

Comment: I now got it to work!  Removed the http after src.  When I tested it on the webserver it worked very well!  Had used a local machine before when I had the problems...  Thanks for answer.